# How to get image URL with GraphQL?

Tags: 8

Let's say I have a field *image* in a *Product* entity. When I query a *Product*, I'd like to include the URL of the field *image* in the response.

The documentation states we can use [`image_url`](https://drupal-graphql.gitbook.io/graphql/v/8.x-4.x/data-producers/built-in#image-data-producers).

According to [this issue](https://github.com/drupal-graphql/graphql/issues/882) I tried the following but I still get `null` for my field in the response.

```
$registry->addFieldResolver('Product', 'image',
  $builder->compose(
    $builder->produce('property_path')
      ->map('type', $builder->fromValue('entity:product'))
      ->map('value', $builder->fromParent())
      ->map('path', $builder->fromValue('field_image.value')), // not sure if value is the correct property here
    $builder->produce('image_url')
      ->map('entity', $builder->fromParent())
      ->map('field', $builder->fromValue('field_image'))
  )
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property of `field_image.value` is wrong, it should be `field_image.entity`.

```
$registry->addFieldResolver('Product', 'image',
  $builder->compose(
    $builder->produce('property_path')
      ->map('type', $builder->fromValue('entity:product'))
      ->map('value', $builder->fromParent())
      ->map('path', $builder->fromValue('field_image.entity')),         
    $builder->produce('image_url')
      ->map('entity', $builder->fromParent())
      ->map('field', $builder->fromValue('field_image'))
  )
);
```